# how do I achieve higher resolution smoothing?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm accessing higher resolutions than the current chart which produces a stepped chart. This can be useful but im trying to impliment a smoothed version as well. The problem im having is the smoothing seems to have spikes still based on the step to the next level.

I want to use TEMA which is.

```
e = ema(MASource, MAPeriod)
3 * (e - ema(e, MAPeriod)) + ema(ema(e, MAPeriod), MAPeriod)
```

Is there a way of smoothing the steps from a higher timeframe which im missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `security()`

current_ma =  e = `ema(MASource, MAPeriod)`

higher_tf_ma = `security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", current_ma)`

1W is higher timeframe, you can change to 60, 240, 1D, 1W, 1M, 12M

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i smooth the line out though? I get steps the size of each of the time periods, or if i do manage to smooth it i get a pinch point at the start of each time period

Answer (score 0):

Use barmerge.gaps_on in request.security() function.

```
higher_tf_ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", current_ma, barmerge.gaps_on)
```

Comment: This will give you stepped line on lower timeframes. The question is about how to remove the steps. Build in indicators seem to give a smoothened line.